# How to assert when editing or deleting a row?

Tags: postman

I am very new to Postman.I did a simple POST request with a simple json request. Next i did the PUT and Delete requests. I need to write test scripts on these two methods that assert whether the row is edited succesfully or not and check it , and whether the row is deleted or not and check it . I appriciate every help . Thanks.  http://prntscr.com/odhal6   http://prntscr.com/of408q    http://prntscr.com/of40du

Comment: What have you tried so far? This seems like a very simple case of simply making the initial request again to make sure the row in question has been updated/deleted.

Comment: Hi , i have attached some screenshots , if you can help me a little i will appriciate it a lot ,  i just want to make sure the row in question has been updated/deleted

Answer (score 0):

Your question is little bit creating confusing but i trying to suggest as per the API behaviors

1. Every request make with separate method eg. GET,POST,PUT,DELETE , as per api rules.
2. Understand the use of these method like

   **Method -- used for**

   GET -- Fetch data

   POST -- Insert data

   PUT -- Update data

   DELETE -- Delete data

Hope you understand that all are separate event so not occurs at same action in API.

Comment: Thanks for replying . I did separate methods . I I need to write test scripts(cuz im new to them) on these methods to assert whether the row is edited succesfully or not and check it , and whether the row is deleted or not and check it . This is POST request  http://prntscr.com/of4c43   http://prntscr.com/of4cg2  , where i save the last entered ID , now i want to edit that id and assert that edition , next i want to delete that id and assert that deletion and so..